# Utilizando o repositório do JPA

Tags: java, spring, orm, jpa-2.0, spring-data

No ultimo sábado apresentei meu TCC na faculdade e vi que preciso melhorar o projeto apresentado. O sistema recebe notas fiscais em formato `XML` e as manipula. Peguei como base o sistema na empresa onde faço estágio. Utiliza-se Primefaces, JSF, Spring IoC, Hibernate.

Eu então comecei a ler algumas coisas buscadas no Google, me deixaram talvez confuso, mas vou informar o que entendi.

O repositório seria uma classe para buscar informações no banco de dados ou no local onde as informações foram persistidas. Mas no caso do `JpaRepository` ele provê a ligação a determinada classe do `Model` com possibilidade de persistir no banco de dados.

Estou correto?

Li que esta implementação é uma boa, pois o `DAO` é abstraído pelo `ORM` da JPA. Então não haveria necessidade de implementar uma classe `DAO`.

Gostaria da ideia dos colegas para saber o que está certo em se pensar e o que está errado.

E se usando a `interface JpaRepository` é possível fazer uma classe abstrata para depois minhas classes implementadas como repositório estenderem dela? E trabalhar em conjunto com o `service`?

Teriam algum codigo de exemplo ou link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em geral você está correto.

## [*Repository Pattern*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

*Repository* é um padrão de projeto similar ao DAO (*Data Access Object*) no sentido de que seu objetivo é abstrair o acesso a dados de forma genérica a partir do seu modelo. A diferença é que o *Repository* procura representar os dados como uma coleção de elementos, lembrando mesmo uma `Collection`.

## [Spring Data Jpa](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)

O projeto Spring Data Jpa facilita a implementação do padrão *Repository* através de AOP (*Aspect Oriented Programming* - programação orientada a aspectos).

Utilizando-se apenas de uma interface, o Spring irá "gerar" dinamicamente a implementação dos métodos de acesso a dados. Estender a interface `JpaRepository` é opcional, mas a vantagem é ela já vem com vários de métodos genéricos de CRUD e você não precisa redefinir todos eles.

A princípio pode ser um pouco estranho usar este projeto do Spring. Quem não conhece AOP e como o Spring Data funciona vai perder um tempo procurando a implementação das interfaces.

Criar novos métodos simplesmente através das assinaturas é muito fácil. Veja este exemplo:

```java
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long> {
    Cliente findByNome(String nome);
    Page<Cliente> findByCidadeAndEstado(Cidade cidade, Estado, estado, Pageable pageable);
}
```

A princípio podemos perguntar: o que o Spring faz com isso?

Primeiro o prefixo `findBy` nos nomes dos métodos significa que será um método de consulta.

O que vem se seguida é como uma expressão que define quais atributos serão usados como filtros. No primeiro exemplo, `findByNome`, significa, pesquise pelo atributo `nome` usando o valor passado no primeiro parâmetro. No segundo exemplo, a query gerada utilizará uma expressão com o operador `AND` considerando os atributos `cidade` e `estado`.

Além disso, o parâmetro especial do tipo `Pageable` diz que o resultado será paginado. Note que o retorno do método é uma "página de clientes".

Veja a documentação sobre [criação de queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods) para maiores detalhes.

Alternativamente, você pode especificar uma query JPA ou nativa qualquer através da anotação @Query. Veja a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Exemplo de query JPA:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname like %?1")
  List<User> findByFirstnameEndsWith(String firstname);

}
```

Exemplo de query nativa:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS = ?0", nativeQuery = true)
  User findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}
```

## Customizando o Spring Data Jpa

Existem basicamente duas formas de customizar ainda mais o Spring Data JPA:

### Criando uma implementação específica

Se para apenas um caso você precisar mesmo fazer uma implementação de métodos, é possível. Para isso, se você tiver uma interface `ClienteRepository`:

1. Crie uma interface `ClienteRepositoryCustom` com os métodos que deseja implementar.
2. Crie no mesmo pacote uma classe `ClienteRepositoryImpl` implementando esta interface.
3. Faça a interface `ClienteRepository` estender a interface `ClienteRepositoryCustom`

Veja a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations).

### Criando uma interface "genérica"

Caso você tenha métodos que deseja ter em todos os repositórios, mas que não estão presentes na interface `JpaRepository`, você pode criar um interface genérica com esses métodos e fazer seus repositórios estenderem essa interface.

### Substituindo a implementação do JpaRepository

Bem, toda a mágica tem um truque por trás dos bastidores. Existe, sim, uma implementação disso tudo e você pode estendê-la conforma seus objetivos.

Eu mesmo fiz isso em um projeto recente para permitir uma busca dinâmica usando um mapa, onde cada entrada do mapa é adicionada automaticamente à cláusulas de pesquisa.

Creio que descrever todo o processo está fora do escopo da resposta, além de alongar muito o conteúdo. Então vou deixar o link de um dos artigos que usei para fazer a implementação é [*Customizing Spring Data JPA Repository*](http://java.dzone.com/articles/customizing-spring-data-jpa).

Por um lado, criar sua versão estendida do `JpaRepository` não é muito complicado, mas sugiro que tente resolver questões específicas usando as abordagens mais específicas já mencionadas. Pense duas vezes antes de criar ou sobrescrever métodos que afetam todas as suas classes.

Comment: obrigado por sua resposta, mas durante uma leitura uma dúvida me chamou a atenção até mesmo de outro material que li, no material dizia que automaticamente o `Spring` implementaria os métodos para eu através dos atributos da classe, correto? Se sim, no meu exemplo não ocorre.

Comment: @Macario1983 Não entendi o que você quis dizer com "no meu exemplo não ocorre". De qualquer forma, só para esclarecer, se você tiver uma entidade JPA `Cliente` com um atributo `String nome` e criar uma assinatura `Cliente findByNome(String nome);`, o Spring Data Jpa consegue criar uma query mais ou menos assim: `select c from Cliente c where nome = :nome`.

Comment: @Macario1983 mas você só vê isso no momento da execução.

Comment: no meu exemplo, seria o código de teste no ´Eclipse´, conforme eu estava vendo neste tutorial, se eu não entendi errado, automaticamente pelos atributos da classe ´model´ seriam criados métodos de pesquisa (`findBy`)  com cada atributo da classe, por isso meu comentário. http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/22/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa/

Comment: @Macario1983 Não, não é isso que ocorre. O Spring não cria métodos automaticamente para cadas atributo, até porque isso seria um grande desperdício. Ele cria métodos de acordo com as assinaturas que estão na interaface. O que está descrito no último tópico da minha resposta é que eu criei um método genérico de pesquisa baseado num mapa. Se o mapa tiver a entrada `nome = "José"` ou `idade = 30`, então a query teria o seguinte filtro: `where nome like 'José%' and idade = 30`. No entanto, eu tive que fazer essa implementação manualmente.

Comment: e você implementa sem DAO? E o quanto bom isso te traz da sua implementação?

Comment: No projeto em que citei, não tenho a camada DAO. As camadas são: Controller (ManagedBeans do JSF), Service (regras de negócio em spring beans) e Repository (repositórios do Spring). Uma grande vantagem do repository é não perder tempo implementando cada método DAO (que na maioria das vezes é cópia um do outro). Isso evita que um desenvolvedor introduza lógica incorreta de acesso a banco (esquecendo de fechar conexões, setando parâmetros incorretos, etc.). Entretanto, o mesmo efeito poderia ser alcançado criando DAOs genéricos, os quais você estende e obtém a implementação dos métodos básicos.

Comment: @Macario1983 Esqueci de citar você no comentário anterior.

Comment: O link que você passou o autor faz algumas coisas a mais que fica complicado realmente para que esta iniciando entender, algumas declarações de objetos na classe, mas acaba que o `EntityManager` faz o papel do `HibernateSessionFactory` que criamos né? Este tipo de abordagem como fica em relação ao padrão `OpenSessionInView`? Ou este padrão deve-se utilizar o que próprio do Spring?

Comment: @Macario1983 O `EntityManager` é equivalente ao `HibernateSession`, porém aquele faz parte da especificação JPA e o outro é específico do Hibernate. Em geral, para novas implementações, é melhor usar padrão JPA. Isso não muda muita coisa em relação ao `OpenSessionInView`, porém este é um padrão [não recomendado](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103363/why-is-hibernate-open-session-in-view-considered-a-bad-practice).  Eu sempre tento usar algo como *session per request* (uma sessão/entitymanager/conexão por requisição.

Comment: te pergunto do padrão que você usa ao invés do `OSIV` porque durante eu criar o programa do TCC, usando como base o sistema da empresa, eu vi que a todo momento era chamado a classe `Open Session In View`, e fora que tive outro problema, que as transações era abertas a nível de requisição `HTTP`, porque digo isso, pois meu programa tinha como propósito ou o usuário inserir uma coleção de arquivos ou os arquivos baixados direto do servidor de `e-mail`, quando a transação ocorria a nível de `e-mail` por parte do sistema, que esta função foi automatizada, transação não era inicializada.

Comment: Na verdade, `EntityManager` equivale à `Session` do Hibernate, enquanto que uma `EntityManagerFactory` da JPA equivale à `SessionFactory` do Hibernate.

Comment: @Rogério Isso mesmo. Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 4):

A **DAO** é um padrão de design que abstrai a **persistência de dados**. Um **Repositório** é uma abstração de **uma coleção de objetos** e os seus respectivos métodos de manipulação. Os dois podem existir num mesmo projeto. A trinca **DAO**, **Repositório** e **DTO** (Data Transfer Object) pode ser considerada uma **Unidade de Trabalho** (Unit of Work).

Uma definição formal de **DAO** tem no site da Oracle, em inglês: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html. Um tradutor pode ajudar.

Um apanhado geral de **Repositório JPA** pode ser encontrado aqui: http://workingonbits.com/2011/05/05/effective-pattern-for-data-access-with-jpa/.

O Repositório JPA é uma implementação especial de Repositório, mas repare que o Repositório se preocupa em expôr métodos que manipulam coleções, e não operações em bancos de dados, como a DAO. No caso do Repositório JPA do Spring, ele se propõe a fazer algumas coisas em automático (busca, inserção, atualização), mas ainda assim o foco é a manipulação de itens de uma coleção.

Pode até ser que os conceitos se confundam porque tem gente que implementa um Repositório com uma cara de DAO (por exemplo, colocando um método chamado `Update()` no Repositório). O correto, no caso de um repositório completamente integrado com um banco de dados, seria o repositório atualizar isso de forma transparente.

Comment: Pois é cara, mas o que eu havia lido, seria que o ´DAO´ não teria necessidade de existir já que convenhamos, se o ´ORM´ faz estas funções não haveria porque, o que achei estranho mas olhando o ´Javadoc´ é dizerem que o repositório não pode fazer a função ´DAO´ mas sim ser agregado a ele, e eu vejo métodos de persistência na ´interface´ do ´JPA´, até gostei pois há um para salvar em ´massa´. Neste exemplo até aborda mais para o lado que você frisa nos comentários, mas como não conheço muito achei estranho o uso de ´DTO´.

Comment: Está correto. Um repositório é agregado a uma DAO porque a implementação tecnológica de tratamento com o banco de dados está na DAO, e o que o repositório precisa pra interação com o banco ele chama pela DAO.

Comment: Parece ser mais interessante implementar por ele, e fazer métodos de persistência, como salvar, inserir e deletar no service, mas fazendo apenas o tratamento por exemplo de deleção de objetos que não tenham o id correto.

Comment: Eu não consigo ver essa diferença conceitual entre DAO e Repositório. Para mim, são a mesma coisa na prática, mesmo que o criador do "Repository" tenha tentado dar uma definição mais "abstrata", em termos de coleções. Todos os DAOs que já vi possuem exatamente os mesmos tipos de métodos que um Repositório, a saber, métodos como "findById", "findAll", "findByName", "save", "persist", "remove", etc. Qual é a diferença?

Comment: @Rogério A diferença é em que nível se trata a abstração. Na DAO há a abordagem tecnológica (por exemplo, as sentenças SQL ficam escritas na DAO). No Repositório não há essa minúcia. Há apenas o método e como ele age sobre a coleção. O pormenor tecnológico (o SQL, por exemplo) é esperado que seja resolvido em outra camada da aplicação.

Comment: As implementações de Repositórios tambêm incluem o código de acesso a dados (incluindo sentenças SQL, se for utilizado JDBC). Eu verifiquei no livro de DDD (do criador do "Repository"), e ele não diz nada contra isso, e não diz que se deva resolver o "pormenor" tecnológico em outra camada. Para mim, a distinção é apenas na forma de descrever a idéia, mas a idéia é a mesma, ou seja, DAO = Repository.

Comment: @Rogério [Veja por favor esta resposta do SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550228/1314276).

Comment: Já vi, e ela está errada, infelizmente, apesar de todos os upvotes. Vocês que acham DAO diferente de Repository deviam ser capazes de dar um exemplo concreto, onde algo é feito num DAO que não pode (ou não deve) ser feito num Repository, ou vice-versa. Porém, não consigo encontrar nada nesse sentido.

Comment: @Rogério Se está errada, lhe devolvo o ônus: você pode provar por fonte fiável que está errada? Também não consigo encontrar nada neste sentido.

Comment: Como é que eu vou provar que algo (no caso, a diferença essencial entre DAO e Repository) não existe? Você já deve ter lido que provar a não-existência de algo é uma falácia (http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/146-proving-non-existence). Porém, eu já ficaria satisfeito se pudessem indicar onde (página, parágrafo) no livro de DDD dá a entender essa suposta diferença (tem um PDF do livro aqui: http://www-public.int-evry.fr/~gibson/Teaching/CSC7322/ReadingMaterial/Evans03.pdf).