# Unidade de trabalho (Unit of Work) com repositório

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository

Em **ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework**, porque muitos exemplos e alguns projetos open-source encontramos um `unit of work` juntamente com o `repository pattern` sendo que o `DbContext` já é um unit of work, inclusive projetos com IoC e DI.

Existe uma razão pra isso? O uso seria apenas evitar o override do `SaveChanges` no `DbContext`?

Comment: Opinativamente falando, acho completamente inútil um repositório num projeto que use o Entity Framework. Vou tentar pensar numa boa resposta.

Comment: Fico no aguardo, quanto aos repositórios muitos adoram, outros odeiam, de qualquer maneira isso é hilário, já vi gente usando repository porque não expõem o LINQ e facilita os testes unitários e a pessoa nem cria os testes unitários. Acredito eu, que seja escolhas baseadas na real utilização, experiência prévia do que experimentar novas formas.

Comment: Não procede nenhuma dessas razões. Estou elaborando uma resposta.

Comment: Por favor me ajude, qual a alternativa para compartilhamento do DbContext ? Supostamente utilizar o DbContext diretamente? como: DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj); DbContext.SaveChanges(); diretamente numa camda de serviço por exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Oren Eini](http://mvp.microsoft.com/pt-br/MVP/Oren%20Eini-4012807), criador do NHibernate, do Castle Framework e colaborador do RavenDB, [escreveu o seguinte texto falando sobre por que usar repositórios não vale mais a pena](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton).

[Ladislav Mrnka deu esta resposta no Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/164051), reforçando que o padrão de repositório vai contra o *Don't Repeat Yourself* e que o repositório não é importante porque o `IDbSet<T>` já é um repositório genérico.

Além disso, passou a ser incentivado o uso de *Expression Methods*, e não mais do Linq, justamente para que o uso do Framework fosse mais natural com uma linguagem de programação, se afastando do conceito de consulta, como é o SQL.

O que confundem (muito) é o conceito de repositório com o conceito de DAO. [Em uma outra resposta que dei aqui (apesar de falar de Java e Oracle, o conceito é o mesmo)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4088/utilizando-o-reposit%C3%B3rio-do-jpa/4120#4120), explico que uma DAO implementa o método de acesso a dados propriamente dito, enquanto que o repositório trabalha com coleções de objetos, sem entender como o acesso ao banco é feito (isto é feito por outra camada). Ora, se manipular objetos pode ser feito por um *Controller* (como atualmente é feito), não há necessidade de haver mais uma camada apenas para manipular coleções de objetos. A harmonização de dados, responsabilidade do *Controller*, é uma manipulação de coleções, e a persistência desses dados, responsabilidade do Entity Framework, é outra. Com isso, pode-se concluir que o padrão de repositório não é necessário quando se trabalha com o Entity Framework.

Por fim, quanto aos testes unitários, [este site explica como fazer o *Mocking* de um `DbContext`](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/mocking-entity-framework-data-context). Com isso, não é preciso um repositório para a realização de testes unitários quando o projeto usa Entity Framework.

Comment: Então você acha que o Controller deve cuidar das consultas diretamente? sem abstração nenhuma? usando os expression methods...

Comment: Acho não. Tenho certeza.

Comment: O fato de não ter abstração nenhuma não poderia levar a um DRY?

Comment: Repositórios levam a DRYs. O Entity Framework permite que o programador trabalhe no nível apenas de manipulação de coleções. Se muitos *Controllers* precisam repetir as mesmas operações, o problema não é da falta de repositório, e sim de design do sistema.

Comment: Só por curiosidade, vc cria uma instância do DbContext em cada controller?... usando service pattern vc passa a instância do DbContext pro serviço?

Comment: Sim, é uma instância pra cada *Controller* que é destruída após o ciclo de execução dele. Como eu não uso *Service Pattern* (porque acho inútil), não tenho como dizer, mas se fosse fazer assim por algum absurdo da vida, provavelmente a instanciação do contexto ficaria na camada de serviço mesmo.

Comment: Sinceramente eu tbm nunca fui mto com cara de patterns mas em ambiente corporativo, infelizmente é uma realidade o uso dessas ..., logo, não posso ignorar.

Comment: Bom, este é o grande problema de ter que lidar com seres humanos.