# Entity Framework DDD Infra repositório Genérico

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como fazer *JOIN* via *lambda* no repositório genérico. Estou seguindo o modelo de arquitetura DDD.

Exemplo:

```
 public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private IDbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        var contextManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContextManager>() as ContextManager;
        _context = contextManager.AuditorExternoContext;
        _dbset = _context.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        _dbset.Attach(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbset.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return _dbset.ToList();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> AllQueryable()
    {
        return _dbset.AsQueryable();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbset.Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing) return;

        if (_context == null) return;
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }
```

Como eu faço *join* sendo que estou numa classe especifica?

```
public class FaturamentoRepository : BaseRepository<Faturamento>, IAnotacaoRepository
{
}
```

Como eu estou usando `BaseRepository` o `FaturamentoRepository`?

Como colocar o dentro do `faturamentoReposity`.

Comment: Você não pode acessar o _dbSet diretamente e fazer a query que você precisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## O Entity Framework já implementa o Padrão de Repositório

Eu já respondi isso algumas vezes, [como nesta resposta sobre Unit of Work e repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%C3%B3rio/33285#33285), mas vou escrever outra resposta porque por algum motivo a resposta é difícil de localizar.

[Vou começar com uma pergunta retirada do Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126/85476). Não é a resposta aceita, mas é a mais votada, e é a que eu considero correta. Aqui se fala que o `DbContext` já implementa uma Unidade de Trabalho ([Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)). A Unidade de Trabalho é o objeto responsável por implementar a abstração entre seu banco de dados e a camada de negócios da sua aplicação. [Ela evita que você tenha que escrever sentenças SQL na mão para o seu repositório](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

O padrão de repositório era necessário numa época em que os mapeadores objeto-relacional ainda não existiam ou não eram bem desenvolvidos, o que não é o caso do Entity Framework, em que uma grande parte de todas as operações de banco já foram implementadas. Dentre as funções de um repositório, estão:

- Trazer registros do banco de dados já serializados como objetos;
- Persistir objetos como registros de um banco de dados.

Isto tudo o Entity Framework já faz, o que torna **completamente desnecessário** implementar mais uma camada apenas para lidar com isso. Além de aumentar desnecessariamente a lógica e a complexidade do seu sistema, o ganho com ele é zero.

## Mas leio em vários lugares que pra escrever testes eu preciso de um repositório.

Sim, porque a literatura ainda não foi renovada completamente. [Neste texto há uma explicação de como fazer para implementar testes unitários utilizando um Mock de um `DbContext`](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/mocking-entity-framework-data-context). Uso esta diretiva em alguns projetos meus e consigo testar o sistema sem fugir do DDD.

## Ah, mas quero implementar o Join assim mesmo. Como posso fazer?

Você pode usar Reflection, descobrir quais são os objetos complexos do seu *Model* e carregá-los dentro do método de seleção, o que, outra vez devo dizer, é completamente desnecessário. A seguinte construção:

```
var objeto = contexto.Objetos
                     .Include(o => o.ClasseRelacionada1)
                     .Include(o => o.ClasseRelacionada2)
                     .Include(o => o.ColecaoDeClassesRelacionadas1)
                     .Include(o => o.ColecaoDeClassesRelacionadas2)
                     .SingleOrDefault(o => o.ObjetoId == id);
```

Já faz esse trabalho de *joins* pra você.

Comment: Eu fiz um curso com MVP da Microsoft e ele recomendar esse tipo de arquitetura baseada em DDD, pelo que entendi, eu concordo com você que fica muito complexo, mas você teria algum exemplo de como fazer isso com exemplo que coloquei, pq minha equipe esta com prazo atrasado eu mesmo, estou perdido.

Comment: [Aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) poderão encontrar um artigo mais recente de como implementar testes unitários tirando partido das alterações feitas, para esse efeito, no EF6.