# Alternativa a Unit of Work + Repository para compartilhamento do DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

Já vi varias vezes as pessoas falando que não faz sentido usar Unit of Work + Repository com DbContext [Unidade de trabalho (Unit of Work) com repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%C3%B3rio/33285#33285)

Supostamente seria "mais certo" utilizar o DbContext diretamente numa camada como a de serviço? como:

```
public class SomeService
{
   public void SomeSaveMethod(Obj obj)
   {
       DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj); 
       DbContext.SaveChanges(); 
   }
}
```

Essa abordagem não me parece melhor, já que deixa a classe de serviço menos coesa e cria uma dependência com a implementação.
Então quais são as outras alternativas? Eu uso o Repository como forma de esconder a implementação aproveitando a Herança para CRUD e o UoW para compartilhar o DbContext (que é injetado por DI na UoW).

Comment: Isso é muito relativo, depende da arquitetura que está decidir utilizar. Mas como citou as camadas, se for pra separar por camadas eu faria uma exclusiva de acesso a dados, contendo o UoW. Deixando a camada de serviço exclusiva para as regras de negócio, E através do serviço chamaria o repositório.

Comment: É exatamente assim que venho desenvolvendo meus projetos! Na verdade a pergunta é mais porque li varias pessoas que parecem ter uma certeza sobre o assunto (de não usar Unit of Work + Repository +DbContext), e até agora eu não entendi da onde isso vem....

Answer (score 1):

Arquitetura é um tema complicado e polemico mesmo. Não existe uma "bala de prata" que resolve tudo.
Muitas pessoas são contra o uso de repositório quando se usa algum ORM porque ele oferece muitas facilidades no acesso e operações com dados e criar um repositório causa a impressão de repetição.
Eu não concordo com essa abordagem porque você está delegando toda sua manipulação de dados para um framework. Isso pode ocasionar problema no futuro relacionado a performance com queries linq / lambda grandes, ilegíveis e difíceis de debugar.
Há outros fatores que motiva utilizar o repositório e outras camadas em um sistema que é a escrita de testes. Se você, por exemplo, coloca na camada de domínio o acesso a dados e a resolução de regra de negócio provavelmente você vai escrever métodos grandes e complexos inviabilizando a escrita de testes unitários.
Uma aplicação web clássica dividida em camadas geralmente contém as seguintes camadas (lembre-se que pode haver várias outras soluções arquiteturais):

**User Interface (Interface do Usuário)**

Camada onde o ocorre a iteração com o usuário

**Application (aplicação)**

Uma outra camada polemica. Nela você trata as suas regras de interface como, por exemplo, transformar uma Model em ViewModel e vice-versa.

**Domain (Domínio)**

Nesta camada você resolve as regras de negócio da aplicação como efetuar determinado cálculo de acordo com os dados informados pelo usuário, calcular o percentual a debitar de uma venda etc.

**Repository (Repositório)**

Aqui você trata somente o acesso a dados. A camada de domínio "entrega" os objetos de domínio "prontos" para que você possa executar somente operações no banco.

Este é apenas um exemplo de arquitetura que é muito comum, mas como disse no início não existe bala de prata para tudo. Antes de iniciar o desenvolvimento que qualquer sistema procure entender bem os requisitos da aplicação para criar uma arquitetura aderente que atenda as necessidades da aplicação, seja fácil de entender e desenvolver.
Lembre-se que temos várias outros tipos de arquitetura como baseada em microservicos, mensageria entre outras.
Dá uma olhada [nesta palestra](https://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow-e-stack-exchange) que fala sobre a arquitetura do Stackoverflow.